# NEST elasticsearch DateRange query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to get results from elasticsearch on a predefined range of dates using NEST api but i dont manage. This example code i am trying to retrieve a week of data but it is ignoring my date Filter and returning older data than my initial date.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

settings.DefaultIndex("wholelog-2017.04*");

client.CreateIndex("wholelog-2017.04*",
create => create.Mappings(
    mappings => mappings.Map<LogLine>(type => 
        type.AutoMap()
        )
        ));

DateTime InitDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);

var filterClauses = new List<QueryContainer>();

filterClauses.Add(new DateRangeQuery
{
     Field = new Field("logTime"),
     LessThanOrEqualTo = DateTime.Now,
     GreaterThanOrEqualTo = InitDate
});

var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<LogLine>()
{
     Size = 10000,
     From = 0,
     Scroll = "1m",
     Query = new BoolQuery
     {
           Filter = filterClauses
     }
};

var searchResult = client.Search<LogLine>(searchRequest);


[ElasticsearchType(Name="logLine")]
public class LogLine
{
    public string Message {get;set;}
    public DateTime logTime {get;set;}
    public string type {get;set;}
    public string logServer {get;set;}
}
```

logstash config file

```
output {
    elasticsearch{
       hosts => "localhost"
       #user => ####
       #password => ####
       index => "wholelog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your mapping and response for this query?

Comment: Thanks for the help, i added the mapping. It is a POCO class filled automatically. I have tried both DateMath and DateTime with same results. The data is being mapped correctly and i can see by debugging that the objects LogLine are filled correctly. I dont know why the Date query does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you didn't explicitly put your mapping and just started adding documents to your index. Try to create a new index like this

```
client.CreateIndex(indexName,
    create => create.Mappings(
        mappings => mappings.Map<LogLine>(
            type => type.AutoMap()
        )
    )
);
```

And use `DateTime` for your field. `DateMath` is intended for building search queries

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "logLine")]
public class LogLine
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime logTime { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string logServer { get; set; }
}
```

After explicitly putting your mapping try to add docs and search against new index.

Comment: Thank you Random for your help, i think i am almost there but still dont get it to work. I have updated the code with your suggestions and tried many different ways with the NEST doc, but with the filter GreaterThanOrEqualTo applied i stilll get no documents. I updated the code on my first comment also in case you can see what i am doing wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: I wasn't able to create an index with the name from your example since it contains `*` character. But if I create an index with a different name, like `my_index`, it filters my documents as expected. Please check `ServerError` property for objects returned by NEST client. If everything is fine and your index name is also ok, please add your code for indexing documents

Comment: I do this because i am using logstash to insert data into elasticsearch. ill add the code to the original comment to show how my indexes are created.

Comment: I think i have to use the * since i have one index per day and im looking for data of a whole month

Comment: Ok, my problem was in fact with the default mapping created by logstash. Thank you Random.